# Bluetooth GATT profile with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, hybrid-mobile-app

I would like to integrate Bluetooth GATT profile using [flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro) to communicate with a Bluetooth device (version above 4.0). Is it possible to do the same using flutter and Any reference /library available for the same.

[Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro)

Answer (score 2):

You can use these two packages to help you 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ble_lib 
example https://github.com/Polidea/FlutterBleLib/tree/develop/example

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble 
example https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/tree/master/example

Comment: Hi im deciding between flutter_blue and flutter_reactive_ble. Why is flutter_ble_lib necessary if i chose to go with flutter_reactive_ble? I see flutter_blue has a higher rating and more activity, but im concerned because its in alpha and so new.

Comment: flutter_ble_lib supports BLEmulator, the BLE simulator. The simulation allows one to develop without physical smartphone or BLE peripheral . see https://github.com/Polidea/blemulator_flutter